# log of parallel computations, how do I prevent interleaved write? lockfile or flock?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, locking, xargs

I see that has been discussed several times how to run scripts not concurrently, but I have not see the topic of concurrent write.

I am doing some parallel computation with xargs launching the commands for the actual computations. At the end of each computation I want that process to access a file and put the results in there. I am getting troubles because the write on the log file happens in a way that each process can access the log file at the same time, resulting in interleaved entries with one line from one run, another line from another run that finished about the same time (which is likely to happen due to the parallel nature of the run with xargs).

So in practice let's say that using xargs I run in parallel several insances of a script that reads:

```
#!/bin/bash

#### do something that takes some time

#### define content of the log 
folder="<folder>"$PWD"</folder>\n"
datetag="<enddate>"`date`"</enddate>\n"

#### store log in XML ####
echo -e "<myrun>\n""$folder""$datetag""</myrun>" >> $outputfie
```

At present I get output file with interleaved runs log like this

```
<myrun>
<myrun>
<folder>./generations/test/run1</folder>
<folder>./generations/test/run2</folder>
<enddate>Sun Jul  6 11:17:58 CEST 2014</enddate>
</myrun>
<enddate>Sun Jul  6 11:17:58 CEST 2014</enddate>
</myrun>
```

Is there a way to give "exclusive access" to one instance of the script at a time, so that each script is writing its log without interference with the others?

I have seen flock and lockfile, but I am not sure what fits best to my case and I am seeking for advise/suggestion.

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: Having each script writing to its own log file and concatenating them when all processing is completed might be an easier solution. Should we assume that this is not an option in your scenario?

Comment: Hi Arnauld, thanks for your input. That was my idea as well for a while. However I would like to avoid it if possible in order to be able to look at the log while "it builds".

Comment: Take a look at https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/ and perhaps this can help with your problem: http://youtu.be/P40akGWJ_gY from 1:00 (Group Output).

Comment: @Roberto: I see. If you want to do a 'human' check during the build, something like 'watch tail *.log' might provide a convenient view for each worker script, though.

Comment: @Cyrus our cluster does not have parallel by default, I have asked if we can install it, but the fact that is absent makes me wonder if I want to embrace it. I would like to have something that runs everywhere, and xargs seems to do the job for the parallelizaion. Since the problem arises only at the level of logging maybe is best to find a workaround for the log and still use xargs. Besides that parallel looks very interesting! I have installed (brewed) on my mac for some tests!

Comment: @Arnould ... I am not sure I follow you. watch will give me the updates on the latest appended stuff in the log, but first I need to build this global log ... that's my problem. I need to assemble together all the logs of the different runs _while_ _they_ _go_ in parallel. I am afraid I cannot see how watch could help here ...

Comment: I was just elaborating some more on the idea of having one log per script and I was assuming that all logs are named something.log and stored in the same directory. In this case, "watch tail *.log" will display the last lines for each log file at once. Not very useful if you have many files and/or many output lines per script, though.

Comment: Why not using a seperate daemon for logging like syslog or rsyslog ?

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251687/bash-and-c-2-processes-in-concurrency-to-write-a-file/270751#270751

Answer (score 1):

I will use traceroute as example as that prints output slowly, but any other command would also work. Compare:

```
(echo 8.8.8.8;echo 8.8.4.4) | xargs -P6 -n1 traceroute > traceroute.xarg
```

to:

```
(echo 8.8.8.8;echo 8.8.4.4) | parallel traceroute > traceroute.para
```

Make sure you install GNU Parallel and not another parallel, and that /etc/parallel/config is empty.

Comment: Is this different from what suggested by Cyrus through the youtube link?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this in the end does the job. The loop keeps going until this instance of the script can lock the log file for itself. Then writes and unlocks it.

The other instances of the script that are running in parallel and might be trying to write will find the lock ... or will be able to lock the file for themselves.

```
while [ -! `lockfile -1 log.lock` ]; do
 echo -e "accessing file at "`date`
 echo -e "$logblock"  >> log
 rm -f log.lock
 break    
done
```

Does anybody see any drawbacks in this type of solution?